# Regex to find missing double quote in csv

Tags: java, regex, csv

We are processing csv files which contain lines with non-closed double quoted entries. These blow up the csv parser, so I am trying to put together a regex which will identify these lines so we can delete them from the files before trying to process them.

In the following example, the csv parser gets to line 2 and includes everything up to the first double quote in line 3 before trying to close out the token and then blows up because there are non-whitespace characters after the "closing" double quote before the next comma.

> Example Line 1,some data,"good line",processes fine,happy
>
> Example Line 2,some data,"bad line,processes poorly,unhappy
>
> Example Line 3,some data,"good line",dies before here,unhappy

I am trying to do something like:

```
.*,"[^(",)]*[\r\n]
```

The idea is finding a single line with anything followed by ," without an instance of ", which follows before the line ends.

The negation of the sequence is not working though. How is something like this done?

**NOTE:**

Since people keep suggesting essentially checking for an even number of double quotes, it's worth noting that a single double-quoted csv entry could contain a standalone double quote (e.g. ...,"Measurement: 1' 2"",...).

Comment: you can use a simple quote counter. If your (counter % 2) == 0, you are fine

Comment: That would have been good to include, but yes, I'm going to be putting this in Java.

Comment: The problem with that Fede is that you could include a single double quote within a quoted field (e.g. ...,"Measurement: 1' 2"",...

Comment: Is that a real-world example? So the only *valid* closing quotes are followed by a comma (or end-of-line"?

Comment: Yep, this is a real-world example or I wouldn't be trying to solve for it. The problem is carelessly truncated text fields coming from a vendor (e.g. a 45 character field truncated to 40 characters, chopping off the closing double quote without replacing it).

Comment: How about `^(?:".*?"(?=,|$),?|[^",]*(?=,|$),?)+$`? It matches only valid strings in your cases. [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oT7lN3).

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is

Comment: @Demo, so far, yours is the only solution that works, even on the case I mentioned on zx81's solution (even though it finds good lines rather than bad). You should post it as an answer rather than simply a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
int count = str.length() - str.replaceAll("\\"","").length();

if (count % 2 == 0) {
    // do what you want
}
```

Comment: To copy my comment from above, the problem with this is that you could include a single double quote within a quoted field (e.g. ...,"Measurement: 1' 2"",...

Answer (score 1):

With your current requirements (including your concern about `"Measurement: 1' 2""`, this will select the bad lines:

```
^.*(?:^|,)[^",]*"(?:[^",]*(?:"[^",]*")?)+(?:$|,.*)
```

1. The `^` anchors at the top of the string
2. The `.*(?:^|,)` eats up any characters up to the top of the string or a comma
3. We match a "...
4. and, once or more times, `[^",]*(?:"[^",]*")?` matches characters that are neither a " or a comma, and, optionally, a balanced set of quotes: `"[^",]*"`
5. We either match the end of the string, or a comma and anything that follows

**A note about escaped double quotes**

You may have, in your input, double-quoted strings that contain an escaped double quote, like this: `"abc\"de"` If so, we need to replace our expression for double-quoted strings `(?:"[^",]*")` with something more solid: `(?:"(?:\\"|[^"])*")`

Hence the whole regex would become:

```
^.*(?:^|,)[^",]*"(?:[^",]*(?:"(?:\\"|[^"])*")?)+(?:$|,.*)
```

Comment: This incorrectly matches the following:

`citizens bank atm locations,"www.citizensbank.com/branchlocator/?search=north tonawanda, ny"`

If the comma before 'ny' is removed, it results in catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: It also results in catastrophic backtracking with as little as `citizens bank atm locations,"www.citizensbank.com/bran"` in JavaScript. Somehow the later comma stops the backtracking but, as I said, results in a false positive.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
^[^"]*("[^"]*"[^"]*)*[^"]*$
```

The `[^"]*` that you see repeated all over the place means "any number of non-quote characters".
The `("[^"]*"[^"]*)*` will match paired quotes while the `[^"]*`s will match the unquoted text before and after the final quotes.
The `^` and `$` anchors ensure that we're matching the whole line, not just a portion of it.

Essentially: if there's an even number of quotes it will match.  If there is an odd number of quotes, it will fail.

[Here's an example](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%5B%5E%22%5D%2a%28%22%5B%5E%22%5D%2a%22%5B%5E%22%5D%2a%29%2a%5B%5E%22%5D%2a%24&input=%20%20%20%20Example%20Line%201,some%20data,%22good%20line%22,processes%20fine,happy%0A%20%20%20%20Example%20Line%202,some%20data,%22bad%20line,processes%20poorly,unhappy%0A%20%20%20%20Example%20Line%203,some%20data,%22good%20line%22,dies%20before%20here,unhappy%0A) of the regex in action.

---

If whatever solution you're working in has the option, there's a much simpler method that doesn't involve regular expressions.  Simply count the number of double quotes in the CSV line.  If it's odd, the line has a mismatched quote.

Comment: To copy my comment from above, the problem with this is that you could include a single double quote within a quoted field (e.g. ...,"Measurement: 1' 2"",...

Answer (score 0):

This was a regex someone else gave me the framework for that ended up working with a few modifications:

This will match anything followed by ," with or without spaces in between, not followed eventually by a ", (also with potential white space) and finally ending in a newline.

```
.*,[\s]*"(?!.*"[\s]*,).*\n
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex doesn't really work reliably for that as there are many edge cases. You should try [univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/univocity_parsers_tutorial) as it is the only CSV parser I know that handles unescaped quotes properly.

It gives you the following options:

- STOP_AT_CLOSING_QUOTE - If unescaped quotes are found in the input, accumulate the quote character and proceed parsing the value as a quoted value, until a closing quote is found.
- STOP_AT_DELIMITER - If unescaped quotes are found in the input, consider the value as an unquoted value. This will make the parser accumulate all characters until a delimiter or line ending is found in the input.
- SKIP_VALUE - If unescaped quotes are found in the input, the content parsed for the until the next delimiter is found, everything will, producing a `null`.
- RAISE_ERROR - Throws an exception if unescaped quotes are found in the input

Use it like this:

```
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();                   
settings.setUnescapedQuoteHandling(UnescapedQuoteHandling.STOP_AT_DELIMITER);

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
for(String row[] : parser.iterate(input)){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
}
```

Hope it helps. By default it runs with the `STOP_AT_DELIMITER` setting.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache 2.0 license)