# How to find specific instance of character in string

Tags: regex, windows, notepad++, regex-lookarounds

I have a set of data that looks like this:

```
"20180214T12:34:56";"0012345";"Data goes here";"1-ZZZZZ"
"20180215T12:44:56";"0012317";"Data "goes here";"1-ZZXXZ"
"20180217T12:36:56";"0012355";"Data "goes" here";"1-ZZTRZ"
```

I'm trying to use RegEx to find any instances of a " (double quote) contained only in the "data goes here" section of the data. The real trick is to find only unmatched " quotation marks. Ideally, this RegEx expression will return only the second line, but if we could make it return only the second and third line, that would also be acceptable.

I've tried using something like `\w\D"` (but I can't guarantee that the quotations will never be preceded by a digit) or `"(?!\w)` (but that's generally returning the first quote at the beginning of the data set).

Any pointers you can offer?

I've found the following links:

[Regex to find missing double quote in csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170875/regex-to-find-missing-double-quote-in-csv) 
This one returns all lines in the data set.

[Regex match double quote, but not pair of double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26619242/regex-match-double-quote-but-not-pair-of-double-quotes)
This one returns other quotes in the line.

Edit: `(?<![;\n\r])(?<!^)"(?![;\n\r])(?!$)` This is working to find the quotes in the "Data goes here" section. However, I'm still struggling with only returning rows with more than one instance of the quotation mark.

Comment: What lang / tool are you using? Is `"Data goes here";` always in third place?

Comment: Yes, "Data goes here" is always in the third place. I'm working with a raw text file in Notepad++ (or similar if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be matching expected double quotation marks then those that are unexpected. You are able to do it this way:

Search for:

```
(?:^"|";"|"$)\K|(")
```

Replace with nothing.

**[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/JxBX6S/1)**

Comment: Using other editors you should care about `m` modifier to be set.

Comment: In Notepad++, this is giving me a bunch of results that say "0 length found" or something like that. I've added a solution that I found that finds only the quotes. Do you think it's possible to find an odd number of quotes in a line?

Comment: What version of Npp? In v7.5.4 it works well. You put cursor at beginning of file, you do a ctrl + h to bring up find / replace window. You then select *Regular expression* option. Put regex in find field and click *Replace All*.

Comment: I just updated to 7.5.4 and it's giving me the same result. It's fine though--one of my other coworkers wrote a VBScript or something that ended up being quicker. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You'll find the culprit later. This regex works on your input in Notepad++, SublimeText and other tools that their regex flavor supports `\K` token as in live demo.